# Simple Materialize UI Responsive Side Menu

Tags: responsive-design, materialize, hamburger-menu

I've searched high and low for the Materialize UI equivalent of this (example in lighter weight MUI CSS): -

```
https://www.muicss.com/docs/v1/example-layouts/responsive-side-menu
```

For example on a desktop sould look like this (with ability to show / hide menu via burger icon): -

[image: Desktop Size]

But on a mobile would look like this: -

[image: Device image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I kept at it and came up with something using the documentation (http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html).

I've attached the HTML, CSS + JavaScript below if anyone is interested.

**NOTE:** In my answer there is no burger when viewed at a desktop size i.e. no ability to hide the menu.  I discovered that if I removed the `hide-on-large-only` attribute on the following `<a>` then it put a menu over the top of the existing menu.

`<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse hide-on-large-only"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>`

Also, when clicking out of the menu it disappeared completely! :-)

Ideally it would be nice to have the burger in the desktop size so the menu can be hidnen if necessary but happy enough with this solution TBH.

```js
$('.button-collapse').sideNav({
  menuWidth: 300, // Default is 300
  edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
  closeOnClick: false, // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
  draggable: true // Choose whether you can drag to open on touch screens
});
```

```css
#container {
  padding-left: 300px;
}

#content {
  padding: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
  #container {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- JQuery / Materialize CSS + JavaScript imports -->

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->

<div id="container">

  <div id="menu">

    <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed show-on-large-only">
      <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
      <li class="no-padding">
        <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
          <li>
            <a class="collapsible-header">Dropdown<i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
            <div class="collapsible-body">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#!">First</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Second</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Third</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Fourth</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse hide-on-large-only"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    
    <h3>Simple Materialize Responsive Side Menu</h3>
    
    <p>Resize browser to see what it looks like in (a) brwoser (b) mobile devices</p>

  </div>
    
</div>
```